# How to change a Javascript object with a dynamic path?

Tags: javascript, object

Im trying to change a variable list with newList. The problem is that i dont know how to change the list when it got path added with a function.

Add string to object

```
Object.byString = function(o, s) {
    s = s.replace(/\[(\w+)\]/g, '.$1'); // convert indexes to properties
    s = s.replace(/^\./, '');           // strip a leading dot
    var a = s.split('.');
    for (var i = 0, n = a.length; i < n; ++i) {
        var k = a[i];
        if (k in o) {
            o = o[k];
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
    return o;
}
```

Return path

```
function getPath2(){
   const split = get("path").split('~');
   var newSplit = "";
   for (key in split){
      if(!split[key] == ""){  
        newSplit = newSplit + "."+split[key]+"";
      }
   }
   return newSplit;
   }
```

```
//  this works
//  {afas: {…}, fa: {…}, fas: {…}, af: {…}}
console.log(Object.byString(list, getPath2()));

//  this works
// {afas: {…}, fa: {…}, af: {…}, fas: {…}}
console.log(newList);

// This is not working
Object.byString(list, newPath) = newList;
```

Error I get back:
script.js:420 Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
at HTMLLIElement. (script.js:420:32)

Comment: Please consider providing a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) preferably by an executable [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: You can change `byString` (or create a new method that is similar to `byString`) to accept a third argument which you can pass `newList` to. When you're on the last property in your for loop, you can update the object: `o[k] = newList`. As a side note, this check `!split[key] == ""` isn't correct and will always result in `true` and `for (key in split){` should be using var/let/const: `for (const key in split){`